# Python sys.setprofile() in other lanuages

Tags: java, php, ruby, profile

I am working on writing a few profiles that need to be formatted in a certain way and so on. I am looking for ways to write custom profilers in other lanauges. I came across Python's sys.setprofile method and hoping that Someone can point me in the right direction for finding the sister functions or methods of doing the same thing in following methods.

python's [sys.setprofile(profilefunc)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile) method allows a callback function to be called everytime a function is called and returned. This makes it easy to write custom profile classes, my goal is to write a library that allows for easy profiling in many langues it, it is also going to be made so it can run on production severs.

- PHP
- Ruby
- Java
- .Net
- nodeJs
- your favorite language (maybe there is a popular lanauge that i missed)

Comment: I don't mean to be mean but shouldn't you be using Google for this?

Comment: Its not like google will give me the "sys.setprofil for php" when i tried i got a lot of trash for this. It taken me over 3 weeks to find that python had this function in it I found the built in profilers for these lanauges but want to write my own

Comment: There is no function in `php` equivalent to this.

Comment: @Jonast92 also it would be nice to have a google search result that contains a list of them, this way people dont have to dig though random github projects.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, that is a shame i have seen things like xdebug which i know are zend C extentions but was hoping PHP had something hidden deep.

Comment: @WojonsTech I'm just going to point to the http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @Jonast92 yeah i know this post is on the line but i i am trying to program this but lacking the information on how to get my function called when other functions are called. I am also planning on making this a github project that is why if someone knows how to do it in a lanague i did not list i will gladly add it to the github project

Comment: Okay, you might want to make this question be more "theoretical", I haven't used python for a long time and I'm not really bothering to google my ass off to look for the behavior that the phenomena is suppose to perform.

Comment: @Jonast92, thank you for the suggestion i have added that to the question